# How to handle exceptions in FadeInImage.assetNetwork

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` to display picture. I want to handle the exception when the image is not found. According to the documentation, one should use `imageErrorBuilder`:

> A builder function that is called if an error occurs during image
> loading.
>
> If this builder is not provided, any exceptions will be reported to
> [FlutterError.onError]. If it is provided, the caller should either
> handle the exception by providing a replacement widget, or rethrow the
> exception.

Then I use it like this:

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
  image: myImageUrl,
  placeholder: "assets/images/myPlaceholder.gif",
  imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
    return Image.asset("assets/images/loadFailedImage.png",
        width: 100, height: 100);
  },
)
```

When my image is not found, `loadFailedImage.png` is well displayed instead but the exception is not caught, contrary to what the documentation says. How can I handle it to avoid that exception to stay uncaught ?

Comment: How do you solved this issue. I also facing same issue. We are enable Firebase Crashlytics and it recorded so many error.

Comment: Have you solve mentioned issue? I am also stuck at the same point.

Comment: @AmolJ No, I just let it as it is. It doesn't prevent my app to work, it is just annoying. But that would be good to have a solution yes.